# How to test if a fragment is visible with Espresso

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-espresso, ui-testing

I wrote a very simple `Activity` with a Button. When the button is clicked, I will start a new `Fragment`. Now I want to test this logic in my Espresso UI Test. So I wrote this UI Test for my `Activity`

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
@LargeTest
class MainMenuUiTest {

@get: Rule
val activityTestRule: ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

 @Test
 fun switchToFragment() {
     onView(withId(R.id.btn)).perform()
 }
```

}

How can I test that my `Fragment` is displayed when the button is clicked?

Answer (score 6):

Try the following:

```
@Test
fun switchToFragment() {
    onView(withId(R.id.btn)).perform(click())
    onView(withId(R.id.fragment)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
}
```

If you're just learning about Espresso, the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/basics) is a good place to start. Also, here's the [Espresso cheat sheet](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/cheat-sheet).