# Espresso fragment transaction testing

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-espresso, ui-testing

I am working on the project. I start learning instrumental tests using `Espresso` to write UI testing. I have a bottom view each bottom view tab has a parent fragment & their child fragments. I have done one wrong fragment transaction i.e when navigating toward home bottom view tab from services bottom view tab home is selected but showing services fragment.

I want to test when clicking on the home bottom view tab the home fragment is added or not. I have tried the code like this but it is passing on the wrong case as well

I have also go through the below StackOverflow posts but not working

[Determine fragment change while espresso testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27369760/determine-fragment-change-while-espresso-testing)

[How to test if a fragment is visible with Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491130/how-to-test-if-a-fragment-is-visible-with-espresso)

```
@Test
fun testHomeFragment_isDisplayed() {

    //click on home navigation button of bottom view
    onView(withId(R.id.navigation_home)).perform(click())

    //click on services navigation button of bottom view
    onView(withId(R.id.navigation_more)).perform(click())

    //click on recycler view item at given position
    onView(withId(R.id.more_rv)).perform(
            RecyclerViewActions.actionOnItemAtPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(
                    1,
                    MyViewAction.clickChildViewWithId(R.id.row_more_parent)));

    //Again click on home navigation button of bottom view
    onView(withId(R.id.navigation_home)).perform(click())

    //check that the home fragment is displayed or not.
    onView(allOf(withId(R.id.home_pager), withParent(withId(R.id.papa)))).
            check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed()))

}
```

**How to know which fragment is currently displayed on the screen?**

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: I have not found any solution for this

Comment: As a hack you might to add an extra view in each fragment and check if it is displayed like onView(withId(R.id.first_fragment_view)).check(matches(isDisplayed())). If you keep this view small as 1x1dp with transparent background it would not break your UX.